# Error CREATEing SolrCore ... Specified config does not exist in Zookeeper:default

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I used the following command:

```
./solr -e cloud -z localhost:2181 -noprompt
```

The final message is the following:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1616},
  "failure":{
    "":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted_shard2_replica1': Unable to create core [gettingstarted_shard2_replica1] Caused by: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:default",
    "":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [gettingstarted_shard1_replica1] Caused by: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:default",
    "":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted_shard2_replica2': Unable to create core [gettingstarted_shard2_replica2] Caused by: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:default",
    "":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted_shard1_replica2': Unable to create core [gettingstarted_shard1_replica2] Caused by: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:default"}}
```

Confirmed zookeeper is running

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0]
```

I looked almost everywhere and cannot overcome. Can anyone help?

Comment: Deploying default Solr configuration files to embedded ZooKeeper using command:

/opt/solr/solr-4.10.3/example/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr/solr-4.10.3/example/solr/collection1/conf -confname default

Successfully deployed the /opt/solr/solr-4.10.3/example/solr/collection1/conf configuration directory to ZooKeeper as default

Answer (score 0):

I recently downloaded and installed solr 4.10.3, was going through the official Quick Start using the command:

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

and encountered the same looking exceptions as you:

```
"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted_shard2_replica2': Unable to create core [gettingstarted_shard2_replica2] Caused by: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:default"
```

Looking up in the bash I also saw the error line:

```
bin/solr: line 1085: jar: command not found
```

This was the reason for the exceptions, the "jar" command was not in the current path. After putting the "jar" command inside my path, these exceptions do not show up. It might be the same reason why you are getting the exceptions.

I am on a Fedora machine, and used the following guide to set up jar, java, javac etc. via the alternatives command (but I think you could just add the java/bin directory to your current path to solve the issue):
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59412/cannot-find-oracle-jdk-on-fedora-21/

Comment: You are correct. I performed a 'which jar' and it was not found. After creating a symbolic link ln -s <actual location of jar> /usr/bin/jar the problem was solved. need to investigate why alternatives did not work.       # alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar $JAVA_INSTALL/bin/jar 2           
# alternatives --set jar $JAVA_INSTALL/bin/jar